# What is the variable that refers to the number of likes on sharepoint 2013?

Tags: request, sharepoint-2013

I want to write a request on the search result request webpart. My request should enables me to retrieve all documents that have the biggest number of likes. There is no variable for the number of likes proposed  on the drop list while writing a request , that why I decided to  set a refinableInt00 variable and give it the value : LikesCount but it doesn't work? it means that LikesCount doesn't exist as a variable on sharepoint so what is the variable on sharepoint that would enable me to have the number of likes?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the number of likes using the listitem property "Number of Likes"
This is a code from a Sample console application

```
using (SPSite site=new SPSite("your site URL"))
{
    using (SPWeb web=site.OpenWeb())
    {
        SPList list = web.Lists["Your List Name"];
        foreach (SPListItem item in list.Items)
        {
            //Print the number of likes
            Console.WriteLine(item["Number of Likes"].ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but I had the same question. The problem is the LikesCount property does not default to Sortable. To fix this:

-Open up Central Administration

-Go to Search Service Application

-Click on Search Schema

-Locate the "LikesCount" property and click edit

-Scroll down to Sortable and change to Yes

-Run a full crawl on your content source

Answer (score -2):

Ratings for list must be enable.
List -> List settings -> Rating settings ->

**Allow items in this list to be rated? 
yes ? no**

and

**Which voting/rating experience you would like to enable for this list?

Likes ? Star Ratings**

After that you can access likes by "Number of Likes" field name "LikesCount".
"Number of Ratings" field name "RatingCount"